# Requirement for SKD not found

Tags: java, android, sdk, installation

Hi i'm learning Android (beginner) and I first need to download the JDK  for the Android SDK, but the  [SDK requirements](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=i) clearly say that I need the JDK 6 , which [isn't available](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html). What should I do? Will it work?Why does Android SDK needs a old and unavailable version? , it doesn't make sense

Comment: Please don't downvote my question for no reason

Answer (score 0):

there are a lot of jdk6 versions available in my internet :)
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html

Comment: but ?Why does Android SDK needs a old and unavailable version?

Comment: I mean , not available but it's old

Comment: well I guess because Dalvik was developed for/in Java6

Answer (score 0):

JDK 6 Update 17 with Java EE: 
In addition to Java SDK 6, but still contains the SOA and Web 2.0 enterprise-level applications, such as GlassFish v2.1.1 application server, Web Service, component model, management and communication API used and so on.

JDK 6 Update 17 with JavaFX SDK: 
Technology products in addition to Java SDK 6, but still contains Sun's RIA (Rich     Internet / Interface Application) of: Java FX. 
JDK 6 Update 17 with NetBeans 6.7.1: 
    In addition to Java SDK 6, but still contains the NetBeans Java integrated editor.

Java SE Development Kit (JDK): 
    Just pure Java SDK 6.

JRE SE Runtime Environment (JRE): 
    Only contains execution environment for Java SE.

Java for Business:
Special necessity for business users to upgrade.

JDK DST Timezone Update Tools - 1.3.21: 
    Time zone update tool designed for Java SDK for.

Java SE 6 Documentation: 
    Java SDK developer reference document.

Java SE 6 JDK Source Code: 
    Java SDK source code.

※ recommended that you choose to download:

Beginners: JDK 6 Update 17 with NetBeans 6.7.1 or Java SE 6 Documentation 
Using an integrated editor to make the program includes the development of Java development, and download time needed to develop the development of reference documents.

Advanced by: 
Java SE Development Kit or Java SE 6 Documentation 
Editor uses its own habits, and download time of development needed to develop a reference document.